# Making postgresql query more readable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT
  distinct(date(survey_results.created_at)),
  ROUND(
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (
      scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high', 'medium'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)
    ) * 1.0 /
    (CASE (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium','low') or coalesce(raw#>>'{survey, denied}', 'f') = 'true')) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)))
    WHEN 0.0 THEN 1.0
    ELSE (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium','low') or coalesce(raw#>>'{survey, denied}', 'f') = 'true')) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)))
    END)* 100, 2
  ) AS positive,


  ROUND(
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (
      scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('low'))) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)
    ) * 1.0 /
    (CASE (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium','low') or coalesce(raw#>>'{survey, denied}', 'f') = 'true')) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)))
    WHEN 0.0 THEN 1.0
    ELSE (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in('high','medium','low') or coalesce(raw#>>'{survey, denied}', 'f') = 'true')) OVER(order by date(survey_results.created_at)))
    END)* 100, 2
  ) AS negative

  FROM survey_results
  GROUP BY date, scores, raw
  ORDER BY date ASC;
```

I'm trying to make it more DRY and readable. Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `positive`, you can try this logic:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in ('high', 'medium')
         THEN 100.0
         WHEN scores#>>'{medic,social,total}' in ('low')
         THEN 0.0
    END) OVER (ORDER BY date(survey_results.created_at) as positive
```

(And similar logic for `negative`.)

I think this encapsulates your logic, except it returns `NULL` rather than `0` when there are no matches.  If that is a problem, you can use `COALESCE()`.